# FlatList React Native Lagging

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, universal-react

I have a FlastList that scrolls horizontally and it works smooth. But when I add one more horizontal scrolling FlatList below this one the whole scrolling starts lagging. Any solution to this?

Comment: Can be anything, maybe you could provide some code and be more specific?

Comment: I faced the same problem, all I just did was removed all the console.log
and everything works fine.
and yes as @IgorFilippov said You should provide some code or more details.

Comment: Are you testing on debug mode? Becuase react native apps lags in debug mode but it will be smooth in release mode. Just create a release build and check

Comment: @IgorFilippov The code is given in a previous post of mine. I didn't get any reply there, that's why reposted here. My code is given here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44583082/react-native-performance-issue-while-using-2-flatlists

Comment: @Dpkstr https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44583082/react-native-performance-issue-while-using-2-flatlists

Comment: @RajSuvariya No even compiled a release-apk and this issue persists :(

Comment: It would be a real bliss if you guys could help me out

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: @RajSuvariya The code is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44583082/react-native-performance-issue-while-using-2-flatlists